# Is it good idea to allow users to use remote image url as Avatar?

Tags: html, image, security, avatar

I am working on online community where users will have the profile page , where he can upload the image of his choice or give the url of the remote image .

So Is it good to just store the remote image url and not the image itself and use it like this on profile page like this

```
<img src="remote_image_url">
```

or download the image from remote url and store it on the local/our server for the later use like this

```
<img src="path_on_our_server">
```

i am thinking from the hack-proffing point of view , as are there any issues if i allow users to use remote image and use it as it is instead of downloading it on to our servers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the image, loading a remote URL which you don't have control over is always dangerous.

To expand:

A user adds their avatar as `www.example.com/pic.jpg`. They then notice that you are simply including that URL on your site, so they change their avatar to `www.example.com/hack.js` and you still include this file so now any JS they add in that file will be ran on their site.

A embedded JS inclusion like this is a hackers dream and is DEFINITELY a HUGE security flaw. If you want to read a bit about a real life example of one of these attacks, ebay was caught out by one last year - http://www.infosecurity-magazine.com/news/ebay-under-fire-after-cross-site/

Comment: The script `hack.js` won't execute though. Of course, if the url isn't sanitized there's always the possibility of XSS, but that goes for any user content.

Comment: It depends on how the file is laid out, you could execute a script that's fetched remotely if the software on the server wasn't up to date and the users' browser wasn't up to date. Granted, it is a lot more difficult to execute remote JS now due to google clamping down on it but it's still definitely possible.

Answer (score 2):

Think about what risks you are trying to mitigate.

Whether you let users upload images to your site or add links to remote image locations, bad people will do bad things. If you let people upload images to your server, there could be attack vectors against your server (vulnerability in image processing libraries triggered by deliberately malformed images). If you let people add links to remote images, the remote images could be malicious to target browser vulnerabilities (and your site then appears to be hosting malicious images).

If you care about people uploading profile images that are inappropriate then you will need active curation of some kind.

The Gravatar service specializes in hosting profile avatar images and has a Terms of Service squad to "police" avatar content.

http://gravatar.com

Answer (score 1):

By using the user's avatar url in your code you're actually making all your visitors visit that user's site as well. The user will be able to track who looks at the image and when.

This is pretty much how analytic tools works. By requesting a resource from a third party site, the third party can track your users.